# No signature of method: build_aci103jaxefegg6gjrvqjhnnw.android() is applicable

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I have Flutter project one I run the project I got this error

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':**flutter_keyboard_visibility**'.
> No signature of method: build_aci103jaxefegg6gjrvqjhnnw.android() is
> applicable for argument types:
> (build_aci103jaxefegg6gjrvqjhnnw$_run_closure2) values:
> [build_aci103jaxefegg6gjrvqjhnnw$_run_closure2@3b6a6deb]

Here is the pubspec.yaml

```
aad_oauth: ^0.3.0
  avatar_glow: ^2.0.1
  bot_toast: ^4.0.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  chewie: ^1.0.0
  date_format: ^2.0.2
  dio: ^4.0.0
  downloads_path_provider: ^0.1.0
  export_video_frame: ^0.0.5+4
  file_picker: ^3.0.3
  firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0
  flip_card: ^0.5.0
  flushbar: ^1.10.4
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_link_previewer: ^1.0.4
  flutter_linkify: ^5.0.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.3.2
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_login: ^1.1.0
  flutter_parsed_text: ^2.1.0
  flutter_redux: ^0.8.2
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.0
  flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  flutter_vant_kit: ^0.2.6
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.6
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  full_screen_image: ^1.0.2
  full_screen_menu: ^1.0.0
  geolocator: ^7.0.3
  google_fonts: 2.2.0
  http: ^0.13.2
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  intl: ^0.17.0
  local_hero: ^0.1.0
  mime: ^1.0.0
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.0
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  multi_image_picker: ^4.8.0
  open_file_safe: ^3.2.1
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.0
  permission_handler: ^8.2.0
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.4.0
  redux_logging: ^0.5.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
  stream_transform: ^2.0.0
  super_tooltip: ^1.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  uuid: ^3.0.4
  visibility_detector: ^0.2.0
  stop_watch_timer: ^1.3.1
  dropdown_search: ^3.0.1
  mat_month_picker_dialog: ^1.1.0
  flutter_html_to_pdf: ^0.7.0
  flutter_typeahead: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0
```

Comment: Did you try ```cd android && ./gradlew clean``` command and run again ? because in ```pubspec.yaml``` there is no lib ```flutter_keyboard_visibility``` visible so try to rebuild android part

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani That's what make me confuse I didn't use this package any way I did what said and error still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue but first let me explain the problem it's there is a library depending on Key-Vi and it depends on the latest version of Key_Vi, Unfortunately, the owner of Key_Vi roll back on the latest version so once SDK check on repos it's doesn't find it so the solution was set the version of Key-Vi on pubspec.lock where the flutter engine checks the versions of libraries does he need it to download it
That's all.

Answer (score -1):

I also Faced This kind of error.

> A problem occurred evaluating project '"file_picker". > No signature
> of method: build_5p3xxyak8svirtezca7439nhl.android()

For Me, this occurs due to old gradle version in android build.gradle file.

after upgraded version of

- `distributionUrl`  in
  `android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`
- `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:<VERSION>'`  in
  `android\build.gradle`

This Issue is resolved for me.